# Difference in the location of the buttons among Chassidim

Tags: minhag, clothing, chasidut-hasidism

Years ago, when I taught classes to a mainly Chassidic male group, there were two students in my class whom I had trouble distinguishing. (Yes, I know it's sometimes hard to do this among Chassidim :-) When I approached the two, I asked told them that I often confuse the two. One responded, "What? You can't tell that I'm Satmar and he's Bobover?"

I asked him to explain. He said the Satmar wear the buttons on their coats on the right and Bobov has them on the left. (Or, maybe, I have this reversed?)

Why do different Chassidic sects have the buttons on different sides? What's the significance specifically about button location that's important? Do all clothing buttons follow the same rules, or it's only for the jacket or outer-most clothing? Does this rule apply only to buttons, or would it, say, change the location of a zipper "pin"? (Most coats have the "pin" on the left side.)

**Note:** My question is not limited to the two Chassidic sects that I mentioned.

Comment: Nope, I've seen Satmars with right-over-left and some with left-over-right. I think these two students think it's more standardized than it is.

Comment: @ezra While I know a Satmar Chassid, in my neighborhood (This is a mentch who can make anyone, myself included, dispel any negative notions about Satmar, BTW), I can't say that I've ever studied his bekishe button location. Maybe, next time I see him, I'll ask him "וואָס איז די סיבה פֿאַר די קנעפּלעך אָרט?"

Comment: I remember being told that some chasidim wear the jacket buttons reversed in or to show that they are different from the goyim (who have a standard button location on their jackets).

Comment: @sabbahillel - This is true.

Comment: https://www.timesofisrael.com/in-ultra-orthodox-fashion-you-can-tell-a-lot-about-a-person-by-his-button-holes/

Comment: @ezra, the Satmars I've interacted with use standard (read: right over left) bekisches, although surprisingly, most of them don't wear streimlach (this was on Shabbos)

Comment: Didn't you ask this question, before ?

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt - I was talking of shirts; as for bekishes the only kind I've seen is right-over-left. I've never seen a left-over-right bekishe.

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt I have a tendency to forget my own previously asked questions. I think I hold the M.Y. record for having my questions closed as a dupe of my own question, BTW. I couldn't locate a dupe for this one, though. But, if you do find one, inform me.

Comment: @sabbahillel someone explained to me that the reason for the reverse button position on a kittel is b/c it is placed on a dead person. Thus, when facing the dead person, the buttoner would have the buttons in the proper position (i.e., "mirror" position.) I'm uncertain why similar reasoning would apply to other clothes.

Comment: @DanF The two ideas regarding buttons on clothing for the living which I have heard are 1) not following the styles of the non-Jews, and 2) Clothing for Shabbat is to be distinct from weekday clothing. In context of that 2nd reason, some people (Tzaddikim) are living in a state 'Shabbat' constantly.

Comment: I’ve always heard that the buttons are right-over-left to promote the right side (chesed) over the left side (din).

Comment: @JoelK - This one explanation; others have mentioned that it might be to avoid dressing like the gentiles who wear left-over-right buttons.

Comment: @ezra I'm not sure if this directional change is specific to shirts and specific to buttons. If the reason is based on the din / chessed concept, then, why not put the zipper pin (the piece that you insert into the zipper "station") on an overcoat on the right side instead of the left.

Comment: @DanF - Chasidim do not wear jackets with zippers. :)